# How do I calculate the Fourier Series of a given sound wave?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let's say I have recorded a piece of music and have it saved as an audio .wav file. How do I take this audio sample and manually, mathematically, calculate the Fourier Series and Fourier coefficients of it?

Comment: What do you consider being "manual" ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform. But you should bear in mind that manually doing anything to a signal of $N\gg 1$ samples is practically impossible.

Comment: By manual, I mean manually work it out, not using a function in MATLAB or other built in algorithms

Comment: A .wav file is often sampled at 96kHz for each side. For a sample of 1 second, that makes 96 000 samples to go through. Then, for the first coefficient only of that signal, you will need to perform $2\times 95999$ additions. If the signal is $s$ second long, then multiply this by $s$.